# How to access arrays in symfony's configuration files?

Tags: symfony

Does the symfony2 can handle only flat parameters?

Say we have:

```
services:
   manager:
      class: blabla
      arguments: [%app.vat%]
```

and in app.yml :

```
parameters:
   app.vat: 24.5
```

it works, but

```
parameters:
   app:
      vat: 24.5
```

does not work. Is there some special syntax to access arrays or this is not possible?

Comment: I don't think nesting parameters this way is possible. It could be possible only if app is an instance of some framework class. Then you could use this dot notation. This is the case with, for example, `kernel.root_dir` parameter.

Comment: You can test Yaml::parse function for testing :)

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible. You can access the values from your example in your code like this:

```
$config = $this->get('service_container')->getParameter('app.vat');
```

If this is still not working you should try to rename "app" into something else (e.g. "application"). Symfony preserves the name "app" on many places and handles it in a special way.